# nodejs with mysql , cant get data from db

Tags: javascript, node.js

can't get data from mysql db in nodejs in routes '/users'

```
   app.get('/users', function(req,res){
 connection.query("select * from users",function(err,rows){
     if(!err) {
         res.json(rows);
     }else{
       console.log(err);
       res.send('err here !!' + err);

     }
     connection.end();
   });
 });
```

take much time and then response with

```
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

db connection

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host        : 'localhost',
  port        : port,
  database    : 'test',
  user        : 'root',
  password    : 'root'
});
```

can some one help me to track this issue ,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely `err` is set and you're not ever responding to the request in that case. Did you check this?

Comment: Correct, console.log(err) and see what you got.  Are you connected to the DB?

Comment: i update the code no errr print in console also , i will update the code agian to put db connection

Comment: the console log now  the following err : { [Error: Connection lost: The
 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST' }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved: I defined the MySql port as `8080` by mistake.

I corrected the port to `3306`.